# error in Run PHP code with command line linux

Tags: php, linux, flutter, ubuntu, cron

My system is :
Ubuntu 20.04
Php 7.4
Nginx

I have a php file with following content in /var/www/hamrah.com/create.php path :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('bash flutter create test');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

i run this command in terminal and And this command executes correctly (creates a flutter project for me)

```
 cd /var/www/hamrah.com && php /var/www/hamrah.com/create.php
```

BUT !

But when I put this command in Crontab, the command is not executed properly and gives an error

In Crontab :

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/hamrah.com && php /var/www/hamrah.com/create.php
```

Note: If I put `shell_exec(' bash ls')`  instead of `shell_exec('bash flutter creat test')`  in the php file, it will run well and some commands like the `flutter create` command will not be executed.

**error :** bash: flutter: No such file or directory

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: bash: flutter: No such file or directory
@shingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('bash /opt/flutter/bin/flutter create test');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Cron doesn't read user's environment variables, the default value of `PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin`, usually your flutter SDK won't be located in these 2 folders, so you need explictly specify the location of the flutter SDK. Add this line to the crontab.

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/path-to-flutter-sdk-bin
```

Use the following command if you don't know where flutter is.

```
which flutter
```

Comment: i changed crontab but I still have the same error. my crontab : `SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/flutter/bin/flutter  * * * * * root  cd /var/www/wphamrah && php /var/www/wphamrah/info.php >> /var/www/wphamrah/1.log 2>&1 `  @shingo

Comment: Try `bash -c flutter creat test`, or just `flutter creat test`, I think the `-c` option is required.